# SQL query error in a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.

Here is the code snippet

```
'Update ' + @TableName +' set status='+str(@status)+ ' where id in (Select Sid from '+@tname+' where SiteId=' + str(@SiteId) + ' and OtId = '+str(@OtId) + ' and (coalesce(VID,'''')='''' OR VID = ''' + @VID +'''))'
```

Comment: And what is the actual resulting query you're attempting to execute?

Comment: What is the value of @TableName you are passing?

Comment: print your result query and look

Comment: That is not a sufficient amount of code to determine the source of your problem. Over-simplifying does not help you. If you intend to implement dynamic sql successfully, you must be prepared to debug the statements you are generating. To do that, you have to look at the actual statement generated - you can't just rely on snippets and guessing.

Comment: @JacobH thank you. @ tableName was empty....

Comment: As @SMor suggests and I reiterate... For debugging purposes... Declare a variable to put the statement in and print the statement before executing it. That would take less time to do then submitting on SO and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting leading white spaces using the `STR()` function without specifying the length and this is causing an error. For example `select str(1)` returns `1` with 9 padded spaces.

What also could be happening is that `@status` is > 10. In this case it will be truncated to `****`. For example,`select str(12345678910)` returns `***`.

So, don't use `STR()` for this. Use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`. Granted this may not be your only issue, but I suspect it is based on what you have provided. I would read the comments, as I agree that you have not given sufficient information to debug this code. Pay close attention to @Back's comment and use `PRINT(@yourQuery)` next time

[MSDN on STR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql)

> The specified length should be greater than or equal to the part of
>   the number before the decimal point plus the number's sign (if any). A
>   short float_expression is right-justified in the specified length, and
>   a long float_expression is truncated to the specified number of
>   decimal places. For example, STR(12,10) yields the result of 12. This
>   is right-justified in the result set. However, STR(1223,2) truncates
>   the result set to **.